# Confluence docker: Cannot connect to mysql

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am (still) trying to set up confluence via docker and a docker-mysql file

When I run confluence as a service I can connect to my database just fine.

[image]

When I try to do the same with my docker-container via docker-compose I get:

```
SQLState - 08S01
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Here's my docker compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
  confluence:
    image: eugenmayer/confluence:7.4.0
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        CONFLUENCE_VERSION: 7.4.0
    container_name: confluence
    volumes:
      - confluencedata:/var/atlassian/confluence
    ports:
      - '80:8090'
      - '8091:8091'
    environment:
      - CONFLUENCE_DB_HOST=db
      - CONFLUENCE_DB_PORT=3306
      - CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1g
      - CONFLUENCE_PROXY_NAME=
      - CONFLUENCE_PROXY_PORT=
      - CONFLUENCE_PROXY_SCHEME=
      - CONFLUENCE_DELAYED_START=
      # those are preconfigurations so that we do not need to set our DB creds when installing - you can also
      # no use that and do it manually during the interactive installation
      # TODO: even though it lands in the configuration it seems to not really picked up by confluence during the installation
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_PROPERTY1=hibernate.connection.driver_class
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_VALUE1=org.mysql.Driver
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_PROPERTY2=hibernate.connection.password
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_VALUE2=jellyfish
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_PROPERTY3=hibernate.connection.url
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_VALUE3=mysql://confluencedb@db/confluencedb?sessionVariables=tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_PROPERTY4=hibernate.connection.username
      - CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_VALUE4=confluencedb
      #- CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_PROPERTY1=confluence.setup.server.id
      #- CONFLUENCE_CONFIG_VALUE1=BDYQ-V8CF-XUYW-DIWK
volumes:
  confluencedata:
    external: false
  postgresqldata:
    external: false
```

I am new to docker and I have no idea why it'd do this. Running confluence as a service is not optimal to say the least and a last resort I'd use

Here's the docker compose for the db:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bachelorarbeit_database
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: horizon
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1P@ssw0rt123
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rt
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3310:3306'
```

Comment: Hum...where is your MySQL service? Or are you starting the MySQL docker container separately? Remember that both your services need to be in the same docker network.

Comment: I start them separately. Is it possible that the other container running mysql isn't visible to the container running confluence?

Comment: Docker creates its own networks & two images must be attached to the same network to talk to each other. The easier way would be to have two services in the same docker-compose file, which automatically puts the two services in the same network. Otherwise you will need to attach the two containers to same network manually. I would say, try spin up the containers, Use docker network ls to see the name of the network created by your docker-compose (it will be fairly obvious which one it is from the name) and then attach your MySQL container to that network with docker network connect

Answer (score 1):

If you don't stuck to the MySQL DB, you could use Postgres. If you can change the DB, I can provide you a working docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  pgdata:

services:
  confluence:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    image: atlassian/confluence-server:${CONFLUENCE_VERSION:?err}
    volumes:
      - ./data/confluence:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence:rw,cached
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8090:8090"
      - "127.0.0.1:8091:8091"
    environment:
      - JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY=1024m
      - JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY=1024m
      - JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=${DEBUG} ${MINIFICATION} ${PLUGIN_TIMEOUT} ${MAIL}
      - ATL_DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
      - ATL_DB_TYPE=postgresql
      - ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/${DB:?err}
      - ATL_JDBC_USER=${DB_USER:?err}
      - ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD:?err}

  postgres:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:?err}
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6543:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB:?err}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER:?err}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD:?err}
```

The used variables are stored in an .env file next to the docker-compose file

```
CONFLUENCE_VERSION=7.7.2
POSTGRES_VERSION=9.6

PLUGIN_TIMEOUT=-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=120
#MAIL=-Datlassian.mail.senddisabled=true -Datlassian.mail.fetchdisabled=true -Datlassian.mail.popdisabled=true

DB=confluence772
DB_USER=confdbuser
DB_PASSWORD=passw0rd
```

The versions of the postgres and confluence are set in the .env file.

Run this with
`docker-compose up -d`
and stop it with
`docker-compose stop`

You can execute a root shell inside the confluence with `docker-compose exec --user root confluence /bin/bash`
or a normal shell with `docker-compose exec --user confluence confluence /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are you using 3310 to connect to mysql? 3306 is the standard port for it.

Comment: I'm using multiple mysql containers on this machine

Comment: I tried your setup, sadly I got stuck in the licensing part twice, not sure why confluence gave me a blank screen. Anyway. Did you try to expose the port 3310?  Add 3310:3310

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of MySQL image, there is exposed 3310 as the DB port. However, the confluence definition mentions 3306 and JDBC string omits the port, so using the same.

Moreover, the comment above on docker network will complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a default-time-zone to your mysql instance.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Connection-problem-with-MySQL-5-7-Got-an-error-reading/qaq-p/1399490?tempId=eyJvaWRjX2NvbnNlbnRfbGFuZ3VhZ2VfdmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMCIsIm9pZGNfY29uc2VudF9ncmFudGVkX2F0IjoxNjAwMTU4NjExODQyfQ%3D%3D

Comment: Please add some explanation and example to your answer such that others can learn from it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Try something more assertive. Like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to ... because ... ."